# Yii - no column in result set

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've got something like this:

```
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

        $criteria->together = true;
        $criteria->with = array('user');
        $criteria->compare('t.user_id', $userId);
        $criteria->compare('t.ticket_id', $ticketId);
        $criteria->order = 't.id ASC';

        $answers = TicketAnswer::model()->findAll($criteria);
        var_dump($answers); exit;

        foreach($answers as $answer) {
            if(!$answer->viewed) {
                $answer->viewed = 1;
                $answer->save();
                $ticket->unviewedCount -= 1;
            }
        }
```

But the framework tells me there's no such property as "viewed" but I'm pretty sure the column is in my database (checking in PHPMyAdmin). The var_dump doesn't show the column in the result. Why?

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify what column to fetch

```
$criteria->select = array('viewed');
```

Comment: When I selected only the "viewed" column I get the following error: Active record "TicketAnswer" is trying to select an invalid column "viewed". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias. What the heck? The column is in database and works all fine when I play with it in PMA

Comment: have you checked in same table/

Comment: Yes, I added mysql logging to my.cnf and copied the query. It's in the result (the column).

Comment: This framework is retarded. When I do something like this:
$test = TicketAnswer::model()->find('viewed = 1');
            var_dump($test);
            exit;

The query doesn't fail but the column is still not in the result set. What could it be?

Comment: have you checked in model file whether this column is there or not>